# Find if a value in a columns is in another column

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have housing address and zip code data that I want to see if it exists in another column inside another table.

I have two excel sheets that I uploaded into Python, Table A and Table B. I want to take every value from column 1 (house_address) and column 2 (zip) from table A and use a for loop to see if the value is in Table B, Column 1 (full_address).

Table A:

| house_address | zip |
| --- | --- |
| 124 HOUSE LANE | 12345 |
| 123 home ln | 54321 |

Table B:

| house_address | zip | property_size | full_address |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 124 HOUSE LANE | 12345 | 1000 | 124 HOUSE LANE 12345 |
| 123 home ln | 54321 | 2000 | 123 home ln 54321 |
| 987 strawberry rd | 11111 | 3000 | 987 strawberry rd 11111 |

My code is:

```
# upload tables
table_a = pd.read_excel('table_a.xlsx')
table_b = pd.read_excel('table_b.xlsx')

# create a list from table b and table b of the full_address column for matching purposes
full_address_table_b = list(table_b['full_address'])


# for loop checks if the address is already in my table_B. If it is return the information to # the end user. If it is not then move on to the else statement which will do something else
for i in range(len(table_a)):

    
    # create a concat list of table a full address
    full_address_table_a = str(table_a['house_address']) + " " + str(table_b['zip'])

    # check if the address is already in our dataset
    if table_b.loc[table_b['full_address'].str.contains(full_address_table_a, case=False)]:

        # if it is, then just print the info from table b
        print(housing_df[housing_df['full_address'] == full_address_test])

    # else run another piece of code
    else:
        print("run this part of the code")
```

When I run the above code, I get the following error:

> ValueError: The truth value of a DataFrame is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all()

I was wondering if someone knew what I am doing wrong here. There is also probably a more efficient way to create the above code as well, so suggestions to more efficient code is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply merge them to see which values are common if its the extent of your problem:

```
table_a.merge(table_b, on = ['house_address', 'zip'])
```

results in:

```
house_address   zip property_size   full_address
0   124 HOUSE LANE  12345   1000    124 HOUSE LANE 12345
1   123 home ln 54321   2000    123 home ln 54321
```

If you want to specifically see which are only in `table_a` or `table_b` or both, pass an indicator and then just filter out based on that if needed:

```
table_a.merge(table_b, on = ['house_address', 'zip'], how = 'outer', indicator = True)
```

results in:

```
house_address   zip property_size   full_address    _merge
0   124 HOUSE LANE  12345   1000    124 HOUSE LANE 12345    both
1   123 home ln 54321   2000    123 home ln 54321   both
2   987 strawberry rd   11111   3000    987 strawberry rd 11111 right_only
```

Comment: I think this is one solution, but the reason I am using a for loop is because I am building something that is going to have users input an excel sheet of addresses and will expect to see an output on info for all the houses. The for loop will allow to see if the address is in the master dataset already (if so it will just take data from there. if not will call an API to get the data).

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to use a `for` loop, you can do something like this:

```
df1['full_address'] = df1['house_address'].astype(str) + " " df1['zip'].astype(str)
first_list = df1['house_address'].unique().tolist()
second_list = df2['house_address'].unique().tolist()

common_houses = [house for house in first_list if house in second_list]
```

Then to see the complete data that the full address match between the 2, you can do:

```
common_houses_df = df2[df2['full_address'].isin(common_houses)]
```

which will give you the complete dataset with the common addresses from the 2 files.

Comment: I think this is one solution, but the reason I am using a for loop is because I am building something that is going to have users input an excel sheet of addresses and will expect to see an output on info for all the houses. The for loop will allow to see if the address is in the master dataset already (if so it will just take data from there. if not will call an API to get the data).